# Samba share with guest access as default

Tags: windows, unix, networking, share, samba

I am attempting to create a samba share that defaults to guest access, but will also allow user access if anonymous guest access is unavailable (there are times where Windows does not allow anonymous guest access). I've seen many different ways to set up user access and many ways to set up guest access, but so far I have been unable to find a way to configure this specific usage case.

My current smb.conf file is the following:

```
[global]
    map to guest = Bad User
    log file = /var/log/samba/%m
    log level = 1
    printcap name = /dev/null

    # Buffer sizes from testing done here: https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2279604.html
    # For us, we didn't need to go as high to max out the connection
    socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536 IPTOS_LOWDELAY

    unix extensions = no
    wide links = yes
    follow symlinks = yes

    # Disable asyncronous I/O that was causing NVME Queue timeouts
    # on Lexar SSD systems
    aio read size = 0
    aio write size = 0

    # Improves send speed drastically
    use sendfile = yes

    # Stores username and guest name information
    username map = /etc/samba/usermap.txt

[sdcard]
    path = /path/to/sdcard
    read only = no
    writeable = yes
    public = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest account = nobody
    guest only = no
    valid users = guest, UserName
    

[data]
    path = /path/to/data
    wide links = yes
    follow symlinks = yes
    read only = no
    writeable = yes
    public = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest account = nobody
    guest only = no
    valid users = guest, UserName
```

My usermap.txt is the following:

```
UserName = UserName
nobody = *
```

I have tried a number of different combinations with the guest user, calling is guest, root, nobody, to no avail. Also, general security is not a concern, as this share is on an isolated device, and if someone is trying to access it then they can have full access to pretty much every file. So I'm not worried about how secure (or not) this is.

Another option that would be acceptable is where Windows still asks for the credentials, but leaving it empty or just giving a bad input would result in the the user being assigned guest and being able to access the folder anyway. Currently when faulty credentials are added it just results in Windows saying that the username or password is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 'guest ok = yes' with 'valid users' (note 'guest ok' and 'public' mean the same). Authentication is done before attempting to access the share, so if 'nobody' attempts to access the share and isn't a 'valid user', it will get denied access.

Comment: That does make sense, but I have also attempted setting 'nobody' as a valid user as well, but it will still deny them access. Is there a default 'nobody' password that Unix uses that I am unaware of, similar to how the default guest user is set to 'nobody'?